# Simulating a POST with PHP & cURL

Tags: php, curl, libcurl

I'm trying to simulate a POST to a website based on what I see coming from Live HTTP headers in Firefox.

Here's a copy/paste of the log from the Firefox plugin:

> POST /context?tab=login HTTP/1.1
>   Host: website
>  User-Agent:
>   Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686;
>   en-US; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101206
>   Ubuntu/10.10 (maverick)
>   Firefox/3.6.13
>  Accept:
>   text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
>   Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
>   Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
>   Accept-Charset:
>   ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
>   Keep-Alive: 115
>  Connection:
>   keep-alive
>  Referer: referer
>   Cookie: fontsize=2;
>   JSESSIONID=0000pXE_BK7TjZFzEyNHqOKzXz2:-1
>   Content-Type:
>   application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>   Content-Length: 46
>   loginid=password&password=password&login=Login

And the response that follows immediately after the POST:

> HTTP/1.1 302 Found
>  Location:
>   website/context?tab=p00689
>   Content-Language: en-US
>   Set-Cookie:
>   JSESSIONID=0000oaKlIeeDRWkX5YCiJu5v1lM:-1;
>   Path=/
>  Transfer-Encoding:
>   chunked
>  Date: Mon, 07 Feb 2011
>   14:15:21 GMT
>  Server: WebSphere
>   Application Server/6.1
>  Expires:
>   Thu, 01 Dec 1994 16:00:00 GMT
>   Cache-Control: no-cache="set-cookie,
>   set-cookie2"

Based on my testing, a response that redirects to

> website/context?tab=p00689

Means that the user was authenticated and everything worked properly.

However, when trying to accomplish this via PHP & cURL, I'm being redirected to a page that informs the user that their session has timed out.

Here's the code:

```
// Provider only likes Firefox
$agent = "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101206 Ubuntu/10.10 (maverick) Firefox/3.6.13";

ini_set("user_agent", $agent);

// Cookie
$cookie = tempnam("/tmp", "curlcookie");

// Post everything that was posted to me.
$fields = $_POST;

foreach($fields as $key=>$value)
{
        $fields_string .= "$key=$value&";
}

$fields_string = substr($fields_string, 0, strlen($fields_string) - 1);

// Custom headers
$headers = array(
        "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
        "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5",
        "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate",
        "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7",
        "Keep-Alive: 115",
        "Connection: keep-alive");

// cURL options
$ch = curl_init("website");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "referer");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$output = curl_exec($ch);
$header  = curl_getinfo($ch);

curl_close($ch);

// Debugging junk
echo nl2br($header["request_header"]);
echo "<br/><br/>Output:<br/><br/>$output";
```

The output from that script is as follows:

> POST /context?tab=login HTTP/1.1
>   User-Agent: User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0
>   (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US;
>   rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101206
>   Ubuntu/10.10 (maverick)
>   Firefox/3.6.13
>  Host: website
>   Pragma: no-cache
>  Referer:
>   referer
>  Accept:
>   text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
>   Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
>   Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
>   Accept-Charset:
>   ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
>   Keep-Alive: 115
>  Connection:
>   keep-alive
>  Content-Length:
>   46
>  Content-Type:
>   application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>   
>   loginid=username&password=password&login=Login
>
> Output:
>  
>  HTTP/1.1 302
>   Found
>   Location:website/context?tab=p00697
>   Content-Language: en-US Set-Cookie:
>   JSESSIONID=0000Tl8NL1Hg2dbNv_PEnq-bbvr:-1;
>   Path=/ Set-Cookie:
>   JSESSIONID=0000Zue58y1tXg3tt4XjB8exXw6:-1;
>   Path=/ Transfer-Encoding: chunked
>   Date: Mon, 07 Feb 2011 19:18:20 GMT
>   Server: WebSphere Application
>   Server/6.1 Expires: Thu, 01 Dec 1994
>   16:00:00 GMT Cache-Control:
>   no-cache="set-cookie,
>   set-cookie2"

Based on what I've posted, is there anything obvious that I'm missing? What should I try next? The requests look semantically the same; I'm not sure what I could be doing incorrectly.

Comment: What about the Cookie header from the original POST?

Comment: The cookie required to make the post complete is not of server 1 but of the target server as the cookie would be created at the login point. i believe,

Comment: Correct, RobertPitt. Thanks for the comments.

Comment: Looks like I wasn't clear. The original POST that is shown has a Cookie header. The manufactured POST does not. If the server set a cookie (and judging by 'JSESSIONID') there may be some associated data with that particular session/user which is causing a failure when the manufactured POST hits the server without a cookie

Comment: Good point, typo.. I'll try that and see what happens.

Comment: Lots of upvotes for your typo.. That was the problem. I made a call to a random page to establish the session prior to logging in and it works perfect. Thank you a ton. I wish I could accept your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The one thing that stands out is the following line of code:

```
$cookie = tempnam("/tmp", "curlcookie");
```

Now if this fails to create the file then `tempnam` would return false, meaning that the following lines of code:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
```

are as good as not being set at all, you should keep the cookie file within the same directory as the executing script.

the next thing is:

```
$fields = $_POST;
foreach($fields as $key=>$value)
{
   $fields_string .= "$key=$value&";
}
$fields_string = substr($fields_string, 0, strlen($fields_string) - 1);
```

You do not need to do this as `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` accepts an array so you should be able to do:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $_POST);
```

This will make sure that the entities are correctly parsed.

I also think you can remove the `ini_set` as that's for native functions such as `file_get_contents` and `fopen` streams etc, so double check the line:

```
ini_set("user_agent", $agent);
```

Also I would check to see if there is a cookie already set from the main page, such as index.php as the site may block requests from sources that have come directly to the login page with data.

Comment: Thanks. I've verified that tempnam is working correctly, as I've manually been inspecting the cookie file as it creates it. I'll try to post the array and see what happens.

Comment: Similar result with $_POST rather than splitting it manually. I should probably be encoding each value if I'm going to manually split it, but I'm just trying to get it to work at this point.

Comment: Also I would check to see if there is a cookie already set from the main page, such as index.php as the site may block requests from sources that have come directly to the login page with data.

Comment: Doesn't appear to be based on what I see in the cookie file. It just has a session ID, which is unique in each cookie file (each request, actually.)

Comment: Its pretty difficult without knowing the site your attempting to connect to, as i would like to get a test script up myself